# Priority ordering 'favorite tags'

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

Today when one choose to make a tag a favorite, it seems that all the tags in here are prioritized in the same way. While I may want to include many tags, because they are of interest, I would prefer that some tags was weighted more than others e.g. while I can have both **A** and **B** as favorites, I would prefer to get more **A** questions than **B** questions, even though I also like **B**.

So my feature request is, please add a way to prefer some tags to others.

#### Mockup of interface

[image]

#### Explanation of mockup

The idea is that favorite tags that are already prioritized have a number descriping their prioritity (can be but not necessary weighted i.e. 4 means dobble as many as two).
If they are not prioritized they have an up arrow, which can be used to change their priority.

I have them sorted in the image for better overview, and may be an idea.
Ignore tags does not have any weight (you cannot ignore anything more?).
To edit a weight, one clicks the number or uparrow and either a dialog popsup or the arrow/number becomes an inline number textbox, and one can write the new weight.

Comment: Rather than priority ordering, I'd like to have weights.

Comment: Can you include a mockup of a UI that would make this intuitive for everyone, but also allows one to have "unordered" favorite tags?

Comment: @Cody how did you find the image?

Comment: @Sha The link was to `http://i.stack.imgur.com/HHmyp.png`, and I tried removing the `stack`, which worked. So to make sure it was permanent, I reuploaded it to SO's imgur account.

Comment: I think for high-volume sites like StackOverflow, this is a particularly good idea. But I would not make it as complex as having weights and then seperate tags with no weights. I think it would be enough to have 3 categories: "high", "neutral" and "low". The system would then present questions with as much high priority tags as possible and with the least low priority. The neutral priority would be the equivalent of unordered.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro: Doesn't appear to be a dupe at all; the dupe is about cosmetic reordering of favorite tags, not about changes to the question display logic.